# Is it possible to nest event listeners in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I am using 'transitionend' to run further code, once a 'transition' has ended.

I have been unsuccessfully trying to nest event listeners, so I can watch further transitions, after an initial transition has completed.

As you can see from the code below, I have been testing, trying to stop bubbling and removing previous event listeners first, but without any success.

In the following, the first even listener works, then anything after the second doesn't run.

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong, would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('.image-viewer').addClass('animate animate-out').on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();

    if ( e.originalEvent.propertyName === 'opacity' ) {

        $('.image-viewer').removeClass('animate animate-out').off("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd");

        $('.image-viewer').addClass('transition').on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(e){

            e.stopPropagation();

            if ( e.originalEvent.propertyName === 'opacity' ) {

                $('.image-viewer').off("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd");

            }
        });

    }

});
```

Comment: Note that calling `off()` with no arguments removes all event handlers on the element(s) associated with the jQuery object. Typically you'll want to remove only the event handlers you added, so something more like `off("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd")`.

Comment: Possible? Yes. A good idea? Generally, no. A better idea would be to add/remove a class based on the transitionend event. Then you can use a single event handler which checks for the class and performs the action as necessary

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks. I have updated my code!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How would I check which event is run?

Comment: nesting can be a bad thing because you can end up adding multiple events to an element.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are nesting the same event, you could just set up a global listener:

```
$(document).on( "transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", '.image-viewer, function(){
            if ( e.originalEvent.propertyName === 'opacity' ) {

                $('.image-viewer').off();

            }
} );
```

Comment: I am adding a different class after the first event. Unless I am misunderstanding, your answer wouldn't allow for this.

Comment: Oh, I see. You might want to use jQuery `one()` function for the initial event https://api.jquery.com/one/ and afterward you can bind the function I wrote in the answer